# How do we know electron have wavelength?

Tags: electrons, wavelength

I know many people thought that light is a wave in the past before Einstein came along but what about electron, the scattering experiment could only hint at their existence so how do they know that electron also have wavelength? What physical experiment was conducted to prove that?

Comment: @Avantgarde, why not post your response as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Davisson–Germer experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davisson%E2%80%93Germer_experiment) observed diffraction pattern for electrons. Diffraction is a phenomenon associated to waves. This experiment confirmed the wave-like nature of electrons, and the [wave-particle duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality) proposed by de Broglie.